# How to get keys from nested objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a migration from mongodb to mysql. I have a sub document in one collection, I need to find the data using sub document.

The collection structures looks like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("578506a90420bec15ea33783"),
        "reselected" : "ABCDEFGH",
            "reskip" : [],
            "restatus" : "active",
            "reuser" : {
                "activeListings" : [ 
                    {
                        "subcategory" : "mobiles",
                        "title" : " Mobile 1",
                        "transactiontype" : "post"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "category" : "mobiles",
                        "title" : " Mobile 2",
                        "transactiontype" : "post"
                    } ],
            "reuserInput" : "2",
            "reussdsession" : "303757117"   }
```

I have tried with mapreduce code

```
mr = db.runCommand({
          "mapreduce" : "collection name",
          "map" : function() {     */map/
            for (var key in "this.reuser.activeListings") { 
            for (var key1 in "this.reuser.activeListings"[key]) { 
                emit(key1, null); 
            }
            }
          },
          "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },  /*reducer/
          "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
        })
```

I need output for activeListings

```
{subcategory,title,transactiontype,category}
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to iterate the array and then emit each key. The following mapReduce script will give you the desired key list:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "collectionName",
    "map": function() { /* mapper */
        this.reuser.activeListings.forEach(function (obj){
            for (var key in obj) { emit(key, null); }
        });                
    },
    "reduce": function() {}, /* reducer */
    "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})
```

To get a list of all the dynamic keys, run distinct on the resulting collection:

```
> db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["subcategory", "title", "transactiontype", "category"]
```

Comment: I have checked the code , but the code has "this.reuser.activeListings.forEach", but when I execute it throws a type error.I have checked assigning the variable but still it shows the error.

Comment: Hi, I have executed the code without the quotes, but still it shows the same error,"errmsg" : "TypeError: this.reuser is undefined :\n_funcs1@:2:9\n",

Comment: Thanks, The code is working , I was checking with some other collection